# web.xml. filter or listener is called right after the user authenticates successfully

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have a Java EE facelets web application, with a form-based authentication.

I'd need that a filter or listener is called right after the user authenticates successfully.
I currently added a filter, but it is always called (at the http request where the user authenticates, and also at every other http request afterwards while the user is still authenticated).

how can I tell the application server to call my filter only at the http request where the user is successfully authenticated?

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>successfullLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.SuccessfullLoginFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>successfullLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/authentication.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login.failed</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things are needed:
1. Write the code after the call to the other filters. In that way will it react after the response.
2. You have an url-pattern of /* implying that it will be called always. If you have an url-pattern for authentication, then will it only be called after an url consistent with that pattern.
If you have a new pattern for a successfull Login then is it even easier, because you can then use that as the url-pattern definition.